# Looking for a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am looking for a function (double exponential maybe?). Its curve should look like $\tanh x$, but it should pass exactly points $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$, so that I can use the region $0<x<1$. Is there such a function?

I seems to me that something like $x=\frac{\exp \left(-Cy\right)-\exp \left(Cy\right)}{\exp \left(C\right)-1}$ can, but I don't know how to rewrite it in the format of $y=f(x)$?

Comment: anything to the power of 0 is not 0, so I don't think there is a double exponential function with this characteristic

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar it doesn't pass (0,0)

Comment: Anything wrong with $\frac{tanh(x)}{tanh(1)}$?

Comment: Thanks, I found $\frac{\tanh(Cx)}{\tanh(C)}$ satisfies my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Take any function on Earth, choose two points $(x_0,f(x_0)),(x_1,f(x_1))$ and define

$$\phi(t)=\frac{f(x_0+(x_1-x_0)t)-f(x_0)}{f(x_1)-f(x_0)}.$$

Now the two points are mapped to $(0,0),(1,1)$.